# Is there a single word that means "self flagellation" or "self punishment"?

Tags: single-word-requests

In the back of my mind, I'm almost certain there are at least several individual English word that means to punish one's self. It doesn't have to be physical, necessarily, but it must be some kind of self-punishment. Are there such words? Clinical words are also accepted (i.e. psychological terminology).

Comment: StackExchange..

Comment: [Asceticism](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Ascetism) is a form of self-denial, or voluntary suffering. It isn't always associated with guilt though.

Comment: @Jason That's it! I think that was the word I was looking for! You *must* post that as an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Asceticism](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Ascetism) is a form of self-denial, or voluntary suffering, especially as a way of life. It isn't always associated with guilt though.

Comment: I do believe that was the word I was looking for!

Comment: @WesleyDavid Your question is definitely not the proper question you wanted to ask then.  There are plenty of gurus and sages who believe that asceticism is a path to happiness and self-fulfillment, and I definitely would not call being ascetic "self-flagellating."

Comment: @billare Hmmm, good point. Perhaps my cultural assumptions are to blame.

Answer (score 11):

I can only think of penance, contrition and such words.

Comment: +1: Hahaha. I was just about to answer "penance" when I got the "load new answer" banner. Sigh. C'est la vie. :)

Comment: +1 _Penance_ sounds about right. Perhaps also _mortification_?

Comment: Really?  This gets more votes than _masochism_?

Comment: @Tragicomic You really should have posted *mortification* as an answer.  It is _by far_ the best answer to this question given thus far.

Comment: @advs89: masochism doesn't necessarily imply punishment.  Consider S/M relationships, for instance.

Comment: I thought that self flagellation or asceticism was how one *performed* penance. They don't seem to be the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

Masochism?  Or masochistic tendencies?

Comment: +1:  I was going to put this as my answer.  A masochist would be the person who performs said action.  But I definitely think _masochism_ is the best answer to this question.

Comment: The only thing that prevents me from using this, is that a masochist seems (in my limited understanding) to *like* the punishment. I was thinking more along the lines of someone who was deeply sorry or self-loathing and punished one's self, not out of the desire for pleasure, but trying to atone for one's failures. Then again, it could be argued that deeply sorry people are trying to release themselves from guilt, and thus beating themselves up for a type of pleasure.

Comment: That's a good point.  It's not really punishment if you enjoy it.

Answer (score 4):

Clinically, self-harm is grouped into different categories, but there doesn't seem to be one catch-all single-word term for it--just a collection of acronyms as outlined here from Wikipedia:

> Self-harm (SH), also referred to as
>   self-injury (SI), self-inflicted
>   violence (SIV), Non-Suicidal Self
>   Injury (NSSI) or self-injurious
>   behaviour (SIB), refers to a spectrum
>   of behaviours where demonstrable
>   injury is self-inflicted. An
>   example of self-harm/self-injury is
>   cutting and is the second most common
>   form of self-harm in the UK. The
>   term self-mutilation is also sometimes
>   used, although this phrase evokes
>   connotations that some find worrisome,
>   inaccurate, or offensive.

I've heard people who cut themselves referred to, nonclinically, as [*cutters*](http://www.jimkukral.com/customer-evangelism-to-the-extreme/). Of course, the more specific you get in terms of what harm is being done, the more choices there are for clinical terms describing that particular compulsion, e.g., *bulimia, anorexia*, [*trichotillomania*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotillomania), [*algolagnia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algolagnia), etc. Then there's the whole realm of [body modification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_modification), and a host of other specific terms like [*scarification*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarification).

Comment: +1 for scarification. That could have some literary use.

Comment: I think `automutilation` is another term for this.

Comment: @DiggyF Ooo! Good one. You're missing out on some upvotes by not using that as an answer. =)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is too extreme but *suicide* is also a kind of self-punishment.

Comment: Whoa, i think it's pretty debatable.

Comment: I can think up an example. The most known one is, perhaps, when Judas realized what he had done, he felt so guilty that he had to punish himself. The only one severe enough punishment for him was suicide. But of course it would be much harder for him to stay alive but that was not an option, I think

Comment: I think this is too specific. As you say, it's one kind, and it's going to upset a lot of people...As evidenced by the downvote and the fact that n0nChun's comment has 4 votes as of now...

Comment: It's true.  Suicide is nothing if not self-punishment.  Also, his example proves historically that it has been considered as such for a long time now.  I think this hardly deserves a downvote.  +1 to offset the -1.  (even though it actually does more than offset it)

Comment: @Edwin Ross: suicide usually (but not always) is a form of self-punishment.  However it's only a small subset of means of self-punishment, which makes this a poor answer to the question.

Comment: I have another example. What about seppuku or hara-kiri? Is it not a self-punishment. By the way it is suicide and honourable one.

Comment: In spite of any controversy, it could be valid in some writing scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

You'd describe a person who believes that they are in need of self-punishment as *penitent*.  I think that's more a state of mind than an actual act of self-punishment, though.

Comment: True, doesn't seem to quite fit.

Answer (score 0):

Playing off of Jason Orendorff's answer, the thesaurus entry for "Asceticism" gives some of these similar words:

- Austerity
- Aceration (hard word to find. From the word Acerate, meaning needle-like)
- Perhaps "Stoicism" or "Stoic"

Answer (score 0):

Masochism is the first that comes to mind, but I seem to remember the word misogynist him being used as an alternate definition but I can't find verification for it on any of the online dictionaries.I realize that misogynist is most recognized definition is the hatred of women but I seem to recall it being used in the context that you're referring to. Hope this helps.